# JSoup парсинг изображений из Yandex

Tags: java, jsoup, парсер

Проблема в следующем:
Подключаюсь к Яндекс картинкам, беру URL изображения

```
public void connect(final String query) throws SettingsFileException {
    final String url = "https://yandex.com/images/search?text=";
    final String charset = "UTF-8";
    try {
        Document docImage = Jsoup.connect(url
                + URLEncoder.encode(query, charset)).get();
        logImagePath.info(url
                + URLEncoder.encode(query, charset));
        Element images =
                docImage.select("img.serp-item__thumb").first();
        srcImage = images.attr("src");
        logImagePath.info("src: " + images.attr("src"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new SettingsFileException(e);
    }
}
```

Путь к изображению примерно такой:

```
src: //im3-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=647d9959589f7509b140c18dc93273f9&n=33&h=215&w=312
```

Когда пытаюсь загрузить изображение через ImageIO, вылетает исключение `MalformedURLException`. Придерживаюсь мнения что это из-за того что в url не указано имя изображения. Есть ли методы обойти подобную проблему, или же я что-то неправильно делаю?

Answer (score 1):

Все оказалось просто, нужно лишь было формировать url в таком виде:

```
InputStream inputStream = new URL("https:" + srcImage).openStream();
        image = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
```